# jBPM and logging

Tags: logging, log4j, slf4j, jbpm

I integrate jBPM as an internal workflow execution engine in my application. I would like a way to use slf4j (running log4j2 under the hood) logger in jBPM in two ways.

1. I would like to use it as an audit log. I know that jBPM can provide [audit logging through a specific JPA configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.3/userguide/ch08.html#d0e5332), however this is not convenient in my case and I would like to use a specific slf4j configuration.
2. I would like to use it in the entry scripts etc. of the jBPM workflows, writing for example `logger.trace("Variable a value:"+a.getValue());`

Does such an logging integration mechanism exist in the jBPM?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, and therefore provide the answer here, so that it could be of use to others too...

1. I have implemented a custom audit log mechanism myself, using the [events mechanism provided by the jBPM](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.3/userguide/ch05.html#d0e1866). More specifically, in the class that I handle the beginning of the workflows, I added an event listener which gets notified for each workflow action and logs it to my custom slf4j logger (see next code snippet):

   ```
   ksession.addEventListener(new DefaultProcessEventListener() {
       public void beforeProcessStarted(ProcessStartedEvent event) {
           WorkflowProcessInstance process = (WorkflowProcessInstance) event.getProcessInstance();
           logger.trace("jBPM event 'beforeProcessStarted'. Process ID: " + process.getId()
                   + ", Process definition ID: " + process.getProcessId() + ", Process name: "
                   + process.getProcessName() + ", Process state: " + process.getState() + ", Parent process ID: "
                   + process.getParentProcessInstanceId());
       }

       public void afterProcessStarted(ProcessStartedEvent event) {
           WorkflowProcessInstance process = (WorkflowProcessInstance) event.getProcessInstance();
           logger.trace("jBPM event 'afterProcessStarted'. Process ID: " + process.getId()
                   + ", Process definition ID: " + process.getProcessId() + ", Process name: "
                   + process.getProcessName() + ", Process state: " + process.getState() + ", Parent process ID: "
                   + process.getParentProcessInstanceId());
       }

       public void beforeProcessCompleted(ProcessCompletedEvent event) {
           WorkflowProcessInstance process = (WorkflowProcessInstance) event.getProcessInstance();
           logger.trace("jBPM event 'beforeProcessCompleted'. Process ID: " + process.getId()
                   + ", Process definition ID: " + process.getProcessId() + ", Process name: "
                   + process.getProcessName() + ", Process state: " + process.getState() + ", Parent process ID: "
                   + process.getParentProcessInstanceId());
       }

       public void afterProcessCompleted(ProcessCompletedEvent event) {
           WorkflowProcessInstance process = (WorkflowProcessInstance) event.getProcessInstance();
           logger.trace("jBPM event 'afterProcessCompleted'. Process ID: " + process.getId()
                   + ", Process definition ID: " + process.getProcessId() + ", Process name: "
                   + process.getProcessName() + ", Process state: " + process.getState() + ", Parent process ID: "
                   + process.getParentProcessInstanceId());
       }

       public void beforeNodeTriggered(ProcessNodeTriggeredEvent event) {
           WorkflowProcessInstance process = (WorkflowProcessInstance) event.getProcessInstance();
           NodeInstance node = event.getNodeInstance();
           logger.trace("jBPM event 'beforeNodeTriggered'. Process ID: " + process.getId()
                   + ", Process definition ID: " + process.getProcessId() + ", Process name: "
                   + process.getProcessName() + ", Process state: " + process.getState() + ", Parent process ID: "
                   + process.getParentProcessInstanceId() + ", Node instance ID: " + node.getId() + ", Node ID: "
                   + node.getNodeId() + ", Node name: " + node.getNodeName());

       }

       public void afterNodeTriggered(ProcessNodeTriggeredEvent event) {
           WorkflowProcessInstance process = (WorkflowProcessInstance) event.getProcessInstance();
           NodeInstance node = event.getNodeInstance();
           logger.trace("jBPM event 'afterNodeTriggered'. Process ID: " + process.getId()
                   + ", Process definition ID: " + process.getProcessId() + ", Process name: "
                   + process.getProcessName() + ", Process state: " + process.getState() + ", Parent process ID: "
                   + process.getParentProcessInstanceId() + ", Node instance ID: " + node.getId() + ", Node ID: "
                   + node.getNodeId() + ", Node name: " + node.getNodeName());

       }

       public void beforeNodeLeft(ProcessNodeLeftEvent event) {
           WorkflowProcessInstance process = (WorkflowProcessInstance) event.getProcessInstance();
           NodeInstance node = event.getNodeInstance();
           logger.trace("jBPM event 'beforeNodeLeft'. Process ID: " + process.getId() + ", Process definition ID: "
                   + process.getProcessId() + ", Process name: " + process.getProcessName() + ", Process state: "
                   + process.getState() + ", Parent process ID: " + process.getParentProcessInstanceId()
                   + ", Node instance ID: " + node.getId() + ", Node ID: " + node.getNodeId() + ", Node name: "
                   + node.getNodeName());

       }

       public void afterNodeLeft(ProcessNodeLeftEvent event) {
           WorkflowProcessInstance process = (WorkflowProcessInstance) event.getProcessInstance();
           NodeInstance node = event.getNodeInstance();
           logger.trace("jBPM event 'afterNodeLeft'. Process ID: " + process.getId() + ", Process definition ID: "
                   + process.getProcessId() + ", Process name: " + process.getProcessName() + ", Process state: "
                   + process.getState() + ", Parent process ID: " + process.getParentProcessInstanceId()
                   + ", Node instance ID: " + node.getId() + ", Node ID: " + node.getNodeId() + ", Node name: "
                   + node.getNodeName());

       }

       public void beforeVariableChanged(ProcessVariableChangedEvent event){
           WorkflowProcessInstance process = (WorkflowProcessInstance) event.getProcessInstance();
           logger.trace("jBPM event 'beforeVariableChanged'. Process ID: " + process.getId() + ", Process definition ID: "
                   + process.getProcessId() + ", Process name: " + process.getProcessName() + ", Process state: "
                   + process.getState() + ", Parent process ID: " + process.getParentProcessInstanceId()
                   + ", Variable ID: " + event.getVariableId() + ", Variable instance ID: " + event.getVariableInstanceId() + ", Old value: "
                   + (event.getOldValue() == null ? "null" : event.getOldValue().toString())+ ", New value: "+(event.getNewValue() == null ? "null" : event.getNewValue().toString()));
       }

       public void afterVariableChanged(ProcessVariableChangedEvent event){
           WorkflowProcessInstance process = (WorkflowProcessInstance) event.getProcessInstance();
           logger.trace("jBPM event 'afterVariableChanged'. Process ID: " + process.getId() + ", Process definition ID: "
                   + process.getProcessId() + ", Process name: " + process.getProcessName() + ", Process state: "
                   + process.getState() + ", Parent process ID: " + process.getParentProcessInstanceId()
                   + ", Variable ID: " + event.getVariableId() + ", Variable instance ID: " + event.getVariableInstanceId() + ", Old value: "
                   + (event.getOldValue() == null ? "null" : event.getOldValue().toString())+ ", New value: "+(event.getNewValue() == null ? "null" : event.getNewValue().toString()));
       }

   });
   ```
2. Actually I decided to avoid using the java logger inside the BPMN definition of the workflows, but I think I could do it by passing the `logger` object as argument in each workflow and use it in my script tasks inside the BPMN2. This is the only work around I can think of right now.

   ```
   Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("logger name");
   Map<String, Object> arguments = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   arguments.put("logger", logger);
   ProcessInstance processInstance = ksession.startProcess("processName", arguments);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

To Use Logger in Script Task of JBPM, Please follow below steps:
1. Create Logger Name in `log.xml` file

```
<Logger name="com.jbpm.log"  level="DEBUG"> 
<appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
</Logger>
```

2. Use full Class name to get instance of logger.

   `org.slf4j.Logger logger = null;
   logger =  org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger("com.jbpm.log");
   logger.info("Logger:: Test!!");`
3. Add `slf4j` jar if not added.